# Switch between two textareas only when pressing Tab button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Normally when a user is visiting a web page and pressing TAB button on a keyboard, the selection moves from one element to another starting from the begining of the page.

I am looking for a solution to switch between two particular text areas by pressing TAB button on a keyboard with an initial focus on the first one when web page is loaded? All other elements on the page have to be ignored for this TAB key press event.

How can I achive this?

Thanx for your help!

= Update =

I have managed to make it work under Firefox 12.0 . IE and Chrome do not work properly. Asuming the text area IDs are #ICCID and #MSISDN, the Jquery looks like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#ICCID").focus();
            });

            var $inp = $('.cls');

            $inp.bind('keydown', function(e) {
                var key = e.which;
                if (key == 9) {

                    e.preventDefault();
                    var nxtIdx = $inp.index(this) + 1;                  
                    $(".cls:eq(" + nxtIdx + ")").focus();

                //Simulate Enter after TAB
                var textInput = $("#MSISDN").val();
                var lines = textInput .split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
                if (lines > 1) {

                    $("#MSISDN").on("keypress", function(e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
                    var input = $(this);
                    var inputVal = input.val();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    input.val(inputVal.substring(0,inputVal.length) + "\n");
                          }, 1);
                       }
                    });
                }



                }
                if (key == 9) {

                    e.preventDefault();
                    var nxtIdx = $inp.index(this) - 1;
                    $(".cls:eq(" + nxtIdx + ")").focus();

                //Simulate Enter after TAB
                $("#ICCID").on("keypress", function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 9) {
                var input = $(this);
                var inputVal = input.val();
                setTimeout(function() {
                input.val(inputVal.substring(0,inputVal.length) + "\n");
                      }, 1);
                   }
                });


                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't! Please! There are people who need to be able to focus the other elements in the page using tab! Not everybody is capable of using a mouse.

Comment: @Quentin. Or wants to you the mouse (like I am...)

Comment: just define two sequential tabindex attributes for textarea but avoid to disable focus for every other element

Comment: This page is the data entry page, bar code scanner will be used to scan numbers into those fields

Comment: Do you mean to say that this behaviour should only occur when the user clicks on the textarea and not when he comes naturally to the textarea while tabbing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have found the solution for for my task! It also includes the simulation of ENTER key just after the TAB key event, so user do not need to hit ENTER to go to the new line. Tested with IE9, FF12, Chrome 18.0.x

Here it is:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Switching between ICCIDs and MSISDNs textareas + simulating ENTER key pressing after the TAB key event - START -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#ICCID").focus();
                });

                var $inp = $('.cls');

                $inp.bind('keydown', function(e) {
                    var key = e.which;
                    if (key == 9) {

                        e.preventDefault();
                        var nxtIdx = $inp.index(this) + 1;                  
                        $(".cls:eq(" + nxtIdx + ")").focus();

                    //Simulate Enter after TAB
                    var textInput = $("#MSISDN").val();
                    var lines = textInput .split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
                    if (lines > 1) {

                        $("#MSISDN").on("keyup", function(e) {
                        if (e.keyCode == 9 || e.which  == 9) {
                        var input = $(this);
                        var inputVal = input.val();
                        setTimeout(function() {
                        input.val(inputVal.substring(0,inputVal.length) + "\r\n");
                              }, 1);
                           }
                        });
                    }



                    }
                    if (key == 9) {

                        e.preventDefault();
                        var nxtIdx = $inp.index(this) - 1;
                        $(".cls:eq(" + nxtIdx + ")").focus();

                    //Simulate Enter after TAB
                    $("#ICCID").on("keyup", function(e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 9 || e.which  == 9) {
                    var input = $(this);
                    var inputVal = input.val();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    input.val(inputVal.substring(0,inputVal.length) + "\r\n");
                          }, 1);
                       }
                    });


                    }
                });
            });
    </script>
    <!-- Switching between ICCIDs and MSISDNs textareas + simulating ENTER key pressing after the TAB key event -  END -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Catch the keydown action using jQuery, determine which textarea has focus, and then use the focus() method to set the focus to the other textarea.

Supposing that your textareas have id="textarea1" and id="textarea2". First you can set focus to the first textarea when the page loads by doing :  `$('#textarea1').focus();`

```
$("body").keypress(function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    switch(code)
    {
        case 9:
            if($("#textarea1").focus()){
                //First one has focus, change to second one
                $("#textarea2").focus();
            }
            else if($("#textarea2").focus()) {
                //Second one has focus, change to first one
                $("#textarea1").focus();
            }

    }
});
```

Comment: I do understand how it should work, but I am new to jQuery. Can someone generate a code please?

Comment: I added some code that should do exactly what you want. Are you familiar with the selectors like `$('#myTextArea1')` ?

Comment: I do get an alert saying 'Tab key pressed!'. Thank you for this. Now could you help me with the code swithcing between two textarea fields?
The first field has got name="ICCID", another one got name="MSISDN" . I can introduce IDs if needed. Thanx!

Comment: I have used:
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ICCID').focus();
 });
to focus on first text area, which works great. When I press TAB the focus does not jump to the second one, but to the button below the form which id is completely different and gets stuck there even if I press the TAB button a few more times.
Please advice.

Comment: Ok, have got this working in Firefox 12.0 but still not working in IE 9. See my Question post.

Comment: Why are you doing `if (key == 9)` twice ?

Answer (score 1):

What about this.... Im to bored at work i think..

http://jsbin.com/uqalej/3/

HTML:

```
<input/>
<textarea id="t1"></textarea>
<textarea id="t2"></textarea>
<input/>

<button onClick='window.toggleBetween=true;'>Init</button>
<button onClick='window.toggleBetween=false;'>Destroy</button>
```

JS:

```
var d = document,
    t1 = d.getElementById("t1"),
    t2 = d.getElementById("t2"),

    nodeType, nodeTypes = [],
    i, iLen,
    y, yLen;

nodeTypes.push( d.getElementsByTagName("textarea") );
nodeTypes.push( d.getElementsByTagName("input") );
nodeTypes.push( d.getElementsByTagName("select") );

i = 0;
iLen = nodeTypes.length;
for ( ; i < iLen; i++ ) {
  nodeType = nodeTypes[i];
  y = 0;
  yLen = nodeType.length;
  for ( ; y < yLen; y++ ) {
    if ( nodeType[y] != t1 && nodeType[y] != t2 ) {
      nodeType[y].onfocus = function() {
        if ( window.toggleBetween )
          t1.focus();
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works well on your example, but does not work on my page. Looks like because I have got some Form Fields Validation there.

Comment: Here is the code I use for Form Validation:

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["SimForm"]["UserId"].value;
var x=document.forms["SimForm"]["UserName"].value;
var x=document.forms["SimForm"]["SimCredit"].value;
var x=document.forms["SimForm"]["SimNetwork"].value;
var x=document.forms["SimForm"]["SimStatus"].value;
var x=document.forms["SimForm"]["SIMLOCATION"].value;
if (x==null || x=="" || x=="NotSelected")
  {
  alert("Please note, all fields are required!");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>

Comment: you'll have to set `window.toogleBetween=true`. But this is just an experimental code. It's not recommended to use it..

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript on page load:

```
document.getElementById("textarea1").focus();
document.getElementById('textarea1').tabIndex="1";
document.getElementById('textarea2').tabIndex="2";
```

Comment: This solution partially works. It does not do the main thing, the TAB button is still valid for other elements.

Comment: You can get the keydown event and bind the tab key.