# switching anchor tags on popover with a tab key

Tags: jquery, html, focus

I have a popover message in my webapplication. Something like do you want to perform this action. It has 2 buttons/anchor tags.

When I show this popover, first button is in focus (i'm setting focus with jquery.focus)
Now, when I press tab focus shifts to second button, and after that when I hit tab focus goes back to something in the page ( below popover ). How do I make sure that when I keep pressing tab focus just shifts between 2 buttons ( or n number of buttons and loop back) in the popover and not go back to the page.

Comment: If I understand your question, maybe you need a modal popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try binding the tab keydown, then focus whichever button isn't focused.

```
$("body").keypress(function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which); 
    if(code == 9){
        if($("#button_one").focus()){
            $("#button_two").focus();
        }
        else if($("#button_two").focus()){
            $("#button_one").focus();
        }
    }
});
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10515912/577096)

Comment: what if it's not just 2 buttons, this seems like a bruteforce way of doing things

Comment: Don't know of any other method of doing it.